# Missing NSDate in scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval method?

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access

A simple test --

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    date2 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3];
    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                   target:self
                                         selector:@selector(timerFires)
                                                 userInfo:nil
                                                  repeats:YES];

}

- (void)timerFires{
    date1 = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval timeBetween = [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate:date2];
    NSLog(@"follow: %f", timeBetween);  
}
```

It cause an "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error in "timerFires"

```
Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".
```

I have declared 'date1' 'date2' and 'myTimer' in .h file.

It seems -(void)timerFires cannot got the value of 'date2'.
Could you help me fix it please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm guessing that your date variables are not staying around because you've never explicitly retained them. [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3] returns an autoreleased object. are you declaring the date instance variables as properties that are retained and synthesizing their getters and setters? for example, in your interface file:

```
@interface MyClass {
   NSDate *date1;
   NSDate *date2;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *date1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *date2;
```

then in your implementation file:

```
@implementation
@synthesize date1, date2
```

then you should access them using self so they are properly retained:

```
self.date2 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3];
```

Comment: Thank you Pistachionut!! Before posted this question I had tryed @property and @synthesize the variables，but crashed. According to your answer, "self.date2" make it worked，though I am not fully understand! :) thank you so much!

Comment: Yah, it can be kinda confusing at first. Here's a link to checkout http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/7295-getters-setters-properties-newbie.html

Answer (score 0):

On doing `date2 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3];`, you are assigning an autoreleased object to `date2`. This is getting released before the timer fires. You will have to `retain` the object if you want to use it elsewhere. So do this –

```
date2 = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3] retain];
```

Remember, since you are retaining this you will need to release it afterwards.